# google-services.json file is missing even tho i added it

Tags: android, kotlin

I added google-serivices.json to my file to make up a login page. but whenever i run the app it shows that the file is missing. Also it is in the correct location

Comment: Where did you add google-services.json file ? I mean inside src folder or outside ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to clean project and then Rebuild.
Build > Clean project

and then
Build > Rebuild Project and run it.